# How to obtain byte array from binary string?

Tags: python, arrays

I have binary string which is "00000000000000001011000001000010".
I want to convert this string to byte array and from that byte array,I want to obtain corresponding float value. How it can be done in python?

I tried doing it using `struct.unpack()`.

```
def bitstring_to_bytes(s):
    v = int(s, 2)
    b = bytearray()
    while v:
        b.append(v & 0xff)
        v >>= 8
        return bytes(b[::-1])

>>> s="00000000000000001011000001000010"
>>> print(bitstring_to_bytes(s))
>>> B
>>> struct.unpack('>f',B)
```

Also guide me on getting float value from byte array.
Finally, we should obtain float value=88.0

Comment: `return` is wrongly indented

Comment: Shouldn't the final output be `(176, 66)`?

Comment: Yes you are right. Actually, I am trying to retrieve encoded data from MODBUS transmitter. Consider transmitter is sending data=88. Their encoding method is first they convert value to string,from string to float and from float to byte array(4 elements  or 32 bits). Anyhow I came to know that transmitted value is 88 and bit stream after byte array is as pasted.   I am trying to obtain results using reverse processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to an `int` and use the [`to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) method:

```
s="00000000000000001011000001000010"

def bitstring_to_bytes(s):
    return int(s, 2).to_bytes(len(s) // 8, byteorder='big')

print(bitstring_to_bytes(s))

>>>b'\x00\x00\xb0B'
```

And to get a float:

```
import struct

struct.unpack('f', bitstring_to_bytes(s))

>>>(88.0,)
```

Comment: Now please help me in getting float value from this byte array.

Comment: It's already in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html):

Using `unsigned char` type:

```
import struct

def bitstring_to_bytes(s):
     v = int(s, 2)
     b = bytearray()
     while v:
         b.append(v & 0xff)
         v >>= 8
     return bytes(b[::-1])

s = "00000000000000001011000001000010"
r = bitstring_to_bytes(s)
print(struct.unpack('2B', r))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
(176, 66)
```